# Unable to display data from select input on the plot and in the table (at the same time)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

How can I display selected data from input boxes in data table and show them on the plot at the same time? Currently I am able to select data and display observations on the plot, I can also drag and mark them on the plot to display in the table (which is what I want to do as well), but I also want to be able to filter my data in select inputs and display it on the plot and in the table in the same time. I am sure there must be another condition added in `output$table` but I tried and can either select from inputs or by dragging. Here is what I have done so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# Step 1 - prepare row data

# a) replace NA values in columns

starwars_data_as_table <- as_tibble(starwars)
starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

# b) add missing info

starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
  mutate(
    height = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
      name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
      name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
      TRUE ~ height
    ),
    mass = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
      name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
      name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
      TRUE ~ mass
    ),
    film_counter = lengths(films),
    vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
    starship_counter = lengths(starships)
  )

colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                             "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                             "Birth", "Gender", 
                             "Homeworld","Species", "movies",
                             "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                             "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")


starwars_data2 = starwars_data %>%
  select(ID,
         Name,
         Height,
         Weight,
         Hair,
         'Birth',
         'Number of movies',
         'Number of vehicles',
         'Number of starships')


# 2) Prepare layout

hair = starwars_data %>%
  select(Hair) %>%
  arrange(Hair) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars_data %>% 
  select(Species) %>% 
  arrange(Species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)


srv <- function(input, output){


  starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

    if(length(input$hair) > 0){
      starwars_data <- starwars_data %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
    }
    if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
      starwars_data <-  starwars_data %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    } 
    if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
      starwars_data <-  starwars_data %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    }
    starwars_data
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~Height,
        y = ~Homeworld,
        color = ~factor(Gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })


  selected_data = reactive({
    sel_data = NULL
    ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")

    if(!is.null(ed)){
      sel_data = starwars_data2 %>%
        filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
    } else {
      sel_data = starwars_data2
    }
    sel_data 
  })

  output$table = renderDataTable({
    d = selected_data()
    e = starwars_data_filtered()
    if(!is.null(d)){
      datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    }
    # if(!is.null(e)){
    # datatable(e, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    # }
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Alex already mentioned You should place the data wrangling in the server. Below is a working version of your code. Please not how there is chain of reactive expressions. This is the desing you want to use in shiny. Reactives are quit usefull they are only calculated once as long as all arguments stay the same even when the are called in multiple places.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# 2) Prepare layout

hair = starwars_data %>%
  select(Hair) %>%
  arrange(Hair) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars_data %>% 
  select(Species) %>% 
  arrange(Species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)


srv <- function(input, output){

  starwars_data <- reactive({
    # Step 1 - prepare row data

    # a) replace NA values in columns

    starwars_data_as_table <- as_tibble(starwars)
    starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

    starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
    starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

    # b) add missing info

    starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      mutate(
        height = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
          name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
          name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
          TRUE ~ height
        ),
        mass = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
          name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
          name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
          TRUE ~ mass
        ),
        film_counter = lengths(films),
        vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
        starship_counter = lengths(starships)
      )

    colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                                 "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                                 "Birth", "Gender", 
                                 "Homeworld","Species", "movies",
                                 "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                                 "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
    starwars_data

  })


  starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

    dta <- starwars_data()
    if(length(input$hair) > 0){
      dta <- dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
    }
    if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    } 
    if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    }
    dta
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~Height,
        y = ~Homeworld,
        color = ~factor(Gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })


  selected_data = reactive({
    sel_data = starwars_data_filtered() %>%
      select(ID,
             Name,
             Height,
             Weight,
             Hair,
             'Birth',
             'Number of movies',
             'Number of vehicles',
             'Number of starships')
    ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")
    browser()
    if(!is.null(ed)){
      sel_data = sel_data %>%
        filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
    }
    sel_data 
  })

  output$table = renderDataTable({
    d = selected_data()
    e = starwars_data_filtered()
    if(!is.null(d)){
      datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    }
    # if(!is.null(e)){
    # datatable(e, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    # }
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I do see it more clearly now. The thing is, R and Shiny are new to me and your hints help me to better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I would put all of your data wrangling and manipulation in srv and leave only UI objects in the UI. You are on the right track I think. I am a bit confused by your code though. You have an input called "hair" but you also are creating a dataframe called hair, but then you are trying to filter on "Hair" (capitalized).

If you want the plot and datatable to use ui inputs, then this can be done with 1 reactive expression. Use the reactive expression to create a new dataframe that filters on the ui inputs. Then use this dataframe (starwars_data_filtered()) in your plot and datatable outputs.